# Touches causing hover on elements which appear beneath the touch

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a date picker in JavaScript and CSS. It's all working fine, but I have a problem with touch devices. When the picker appears, it looks like this:

[image]

Clicking on the year at the top (in this example '1983') results in the content of the picker changing to a year selection, like this:

[image]

This works perfectly on desktop. However on mobile (iOS to be specific) the touch event on the picker causes hover on the div even after the touch has ended and the div content has changed, resulting in this effect:

[image]

The year 1980 has been highlighted as though the user is hovering on it, and this element is beneath the touch position which opened this view.

All of the elements on the picker are divs and the styling is done with CSS classes, with the outline on hovered items being added using :hover on the class.

I can provide specific code if needed, but hopefully this will provide enough information to get the idea across.

Comment: It seems this might be caused by a known "sticky hover effect". This page details it and how to disable hover on mobile, but not a workaround to actually get hover working properly. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/sticky-hover-issue-solutions.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

http://mvartan.com/2014/12/20/fixing-sticky-hover-on-mobile-devices

Essentially, it boils down to using :hover on desktop and :active on mobile.